# Geolocation.getCurrentPosition not assigning return value to variable via await

Tags: javascript, async-await, geolocation

Context: building a basic weather app as a part of the Odin Project's full stack web development course.

**What I'm trying to do:** Get user location from built-in geolocation feature in browser to populate app with their local weather by default. I want to send the lat/lon data to loadApp() which will then use this data to automatically populate the webpage with their local weather

**What happens instead:** The function runs the if-statement and says the user denied access before the `defaultLocation` variable is even assigned.

**What I tried**: I tried making both async functions, as I thought async literally stopped the code from running until its promise was resolved, so I don't know how the alert(user denied access) line is ever running.

(I have no html/css built yet, just working from console right now.)

```
async function getLocationFromUser (){
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        /* geolocation is available */
        console.log('geolocation IS available');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            let defaultCoords = [];
            defaultCoords.push(position.coords.latitude);
            defaultCoords.push(position.coords.longitude);
            defaultLocation =  defaultCoords;
          });
      } else {
        console.log('geolocation is NOT available');
        return false;
        /* geolocation IS NOT available */
    }
}



async function loadApp(){
    let defaultLocation = await getLocationFromUser();
    if(!defaultLocation){
        alert('user denied us');
        //code if user denies location service;
    } else {
        console.log(defaultLocation);
    }
}

loadApp().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: `getLocationFromUser` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getLocationFromUser` doesn't return anything when geolocation is supported. Since `getCurrentPosition` uses a callback pattern, you could "promisify" the callback by wrapping it in a `Promise`. Return the promise immediately.

No need to use `async` here as you're not *awaiting* anything in the function.

```
function getLocationFromUser (){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        resolve(position.coords);
      }, reject);
    } else {
      reject('Geolocation not supported');
    }
  });
}
```

```
async function loadApp(){
  try {
    const defaultLocation = await getLocationFromUser();
    console.log(defaultLocation);
  } catch (error) {
    alert('user denied us');
    //code if user denies location service;
  }
}
```

Comment: idk how but my return statement got deleted when I was posting the question. right below `defaultLocation =  defaultCoords;`, it says `return defaultLocation`

Comment: Those things happen. But even so, the return statement would be placed inside of the `getCurrentPosition` callback, and not in the scope of `getLocationFromUser`. `getLocationFromUser` would still not return anything. Wrapping it in a Promise is a way to *return from a callback*.

Comment: Also, `loadApp` doesn't return anything as well. So the `console.log(data)` would print `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks again. And yeah I'm aware of that. That was mostly a placeholder line as I am very new to async code but I know you need to at least follow things up with a .then statement.

Do you really need the second `resolve` statement inside the getCurrentPosition method?

Comment: I've improved my answer. The `return false` wouldn't work as expected. Rejecting the promise seems appropriate here as that would allow you to use the `catch` flow to handle rejection, denial, or error scenario's. What second `resolve` statement do you mean? I only see the one `resolve(position.coords);`.

Comment: Guess I was confusing the resolve parameter with the resolve statement.